# php inserting nothing into table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not an expert in php, but I used it before and it worked without any problems.
But this time a mysterious problem appeared - I have this simple code that normally should work but it inserts nothing into my table and returns no errors.

```
<?php

try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=androider', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

if(isset($_POST['content'])){
    $req = $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO posts(title, content, catgory, date) VALUES("dfdfdfgdgd", "dffdsggdbfgdtdbtghdtgdgt", "android", now())');
    echo $_POST['title'].$_POST['content'].$_POST['category'];
}?>
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the if construct?

Comment: echo your request and then try it directly in mysql, maybe he will be more talkative

Comment: And get the possible error message for the execution of the statement as well.

Comment: how about using `"` for string and `'` for the insert values. might help.

Comment: thank's everyone and specially to BenH, i tried it directly in mysql and it the column 'category' was missing an 'e' in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use **date("Y-m-d H:i:s")** instead of **NOW().**
NOW() is Mysql function so we can use **date("Y-m-d H:i:s")** in php.